# After y = x, the value of x should not change, but why x changed in this script?

Tags: python, numpy

After running this script, both x and y equal 0, 3.14, 0, 3.14, 1.19, 3.14, 2.39, 3.14, 1, 3.14, 1

```
import numpy as np
x = np.concatenate([np.zeros(2), np.arange(0, 3.6, 0.6), np.ones(3)])
y = x;
y[1::2]  = np.pi
```

Comment: when you do `y=x` with non-primitive types in python, `x` and `y` are alias to the same objects and hence updating `y` changes `x` too.

Comment: In Python, assignment statements do not copy objects, they create a link between a target and an object. You will need to set `y` to be a copy of `x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `x` contains a pointer to the array.

When writing `y = x`, you only assigned the pointer to the array to `y`. Because both variables point to the same array, any change made through `x` or `y` will be applied on the same data.

You can copy the array to have a different one: `y = x.copy()`.

Comment: They are references to be more precise.